# What event (if any) does QTextEdit fire when the size of its content changes?

Tags: c++, qt, events, resize, qtextedit

As the title says, how can I receive notification whenever a multi-line `QTextEdit` changes the size of its content?

(*Note:* *content size* is different from the *control size*, i.e. I want to know when lines were added or removed, or changed height because of a font change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTextEdit` has a `textChanged()` signal which will do what you want. From the [docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtextedit.html#textChanged):

> "This signal is emitted whenever the
>   document's content changes; for
>   example, when text is inserted or
>   deleted, or when formatting is
>   applied."

I wasn't sure if formatting included font changes but I tested it and it does.